# C# How do I extract Text from a DataGrid (Not DataGridView)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm using a DataGrid (Not a DataGridView) to display some info, and once I press a, say a save button I want all the data to be moved to a listbox column wise...

Help's appreciated guys! :D

EDIT: (here's the code so I want the data from the columns below to be read)
I tried this : `MessageBox.Show(SMLDataGrid.Items[0].ToString());`
There's no `.Value` option either... or anything similar that I've seen

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SMLDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8" materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BaseIn}"
                Header="Base" x:Name="GrammarBaseColumn"
                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PastIn}"
                Header="Past Form" x:Name="GrammarPastColumn"
                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PastPIn}"
                Header="Past Participle Form" x:Name="GrammarPastPColumn"
                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IesIn}"
                Header="Plural Form" x:Name="GrammarIngColumn"
                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IngIn}"
                Header="Verb Form" x:Name="GrammarIesColumn"
                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

EDIT:I've tried assigning the ItemSource of the DataGrid upon the Save Button press to another list as well through this:

```
ListBox a = new ListBox();
a.ItemsSource = SMLDataGrid.Items;
MessageBox.Show(a.Items[0].ToString());
```

But the messagebox shows the name of the file + name of the class that holds all the strings..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask read this and edit your question if you want no downvotes and a good answer

Comment: Create a class to hold all your data. Bind the class to your DataGrid. When person presses Save, then bind the listbox to the class. If you do not want the data in DataGrid after save, then remove the binding of your class to the DataGrid.

Comment: Provide us some code that you have, if dont provide us more information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably set the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to an `IEnumerable<YourClass>` (if you haven't you should) where `YourClass` is the class where the BaseIn, PastIn, PastPIn, ... properties are defined.

You can set the ItemsSource of the ListBox the same way:

```
listBox.ItemsSource = SMLDataGrid.ItemsSource;

var ic = SMLDataGrid.Items.OfType<YourClass>().ToList();
MessageBox.Show(ic[0].BaseIn);
```

The ListBox has no concept of columns though but depending on what you are trying to do you could use a ListView with a GridView instead: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview